# unable to read configfile using Configparser in Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, configparser

I want to read some values as a parameter using configparser in Databricks

i can import configparser module in databricks but unable to read the parameters from configfile its coming up error as KEY ERROR

please check the below screenshot

[image: error sreenshot]

config file is

[image: config file]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your file is located on DBFS (the `/FileStore/...`) and this is file system isn't understood by `configparser` that works with "local" file system. To get this working, you need to append the `/dbfs` prefix to file path: `/dbfs/FileStore/....`

P.S. it may not work on community edition with DBR 7.x.  In this case, just copy this config file before reading using the `dbutils.fs.cp`, like this :

```
dbutils.fs.cp("/FileStore/...", "file:///tmp/config.ini")
config.read("/tmp/config.ini")
```

Comment: Its working !!!!!!!!! @Alex Ott...love u brother.... by the way  thanks for the explanation....

Comment: kudos and thanks for explanation. it make sense. I have same issue, let me try your suggestion